# C3 Graphs On Load Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, c3.js

I want to use some kind of callback function that will run some code once the C3 Graph is finished loading so that I can change the fill colors of certain points.

Answer (score 6):

Don't load any data in the initialization. Rather explicitly call the load event and pass the data in. Then you have access to the `done` callback.

```
var chart = c3.generate({ /*...*/ });

chart.load({
  columns: [['data1, 100, 200, 150, ...],
    ...
  ],
  done: function() { /* whatever you need done here... */}
});
```

Comment: i was trying the same today but this doesn't seem to work. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geertvdc/e60o24d0/200/ when i move the code from the done callback to a settimeout a bit later it works. any ideas?

Comment: Hi @GeertvdC - that fiddle works fine for me. Here it is forked to a different fiddle, with one data value changed, does it work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/fcw39sr2/

Comment: is the code in the done function actually being executed? i do see a graph showing up but the code in the done callback should make the labels white. this does not seem to work. (if i do it in a timeout it works.)

Comment: Yes, it's running. It's just that there's an error in the code. Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/fcw39sr2/1/ - browse that with your developer tools open, you'll get an alert and then the debugger should kick in. If you step to the next line you'll see your d3 selector is erroring.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this!

Answer (score 4):

The above didnt work for me, I used `'onrendered'`.

```
onrendered: function () { ... }
```

See here: https://c3js.org/reference.html#onrendered

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring an `id` on the graph container (usually the `svg`) with `.attr("id", "GraphContainer")`.
After that, you can bind an `.onload` to it. Something like this:

```
var SVGCont = document.getElementById("GraphContainer");
SVGCont.onload = function() {
    // your code for when it's done loading
};
```

You can also use the event for when SVG elements are added to the DOM:

```
$(document).bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
    // your code 
});
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work, the id was assigned... But the onLoad function was never ran.

Comment: Edited answer. Take a look