# C3.JS chart loaded event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, c3.js

I use C3 to print a graph. However, I have a lot of data, so the loading time can takes several seconds.

What I wanted to do is to put a spinning wheel while C3 loads the data and prints the graph.

To do so, I have a function which:

- starts the spin
- load the data in the graph thanks to the `chart.load()`function (the chart is already created)
- stops the spin at the end of the function

Unfortunately, the data must be loaded in a callback function inside C3 because my function returns before the graph is displayed (and my spinning wheel stops several seconds before the data are displayed in the graph).

Thus, I wonder if there is an event in C3 that says "hey! the graph is now correctly displayed" so I can stop the spin at this moment. Something like

`chart.onFullyLoaded(function() {spin.stop()});`

Do you know if such a function exists, or how I can manage to have this behavior?

Comment: Try the second answer here? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028267/c3-graphs-on-load-callback

Comment: Great! I'll try that. I search before posting but I was unable to find this... Thanks!